# Issue cloning a group using FabricJS (Copy and Paste)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to copy and paste objects onto canvas using FabricJS:

I can get it working perfectly when the copied item is an object. But when the item is a group it messes up.

I've put together this fiddle (its a mess I know) but its a few disparate parts of a larger, more organised script (just enough to replicate the problem).

https://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/xxd6h80t/

With the circle selected hit the paste button and it will copy and paste a clone of the object with a 5px offset. Perfect.

Now that you have two, select them both and try the same thing. The original circles vanish and the cloned ones disappear or move after deselecting???

Here is the paste function:

```
var _paste = function() {

  var activeObject = _canvas.getActiveObject(),
    activeGroup = _canvas.getActiveGroup();

  if (_clipboard.objects) {

    var group = new fabric.Group();

    for (var i in _clipboard.objects) {

      var object = fabric.util.object.clone(_clipboard.objects[i]);

      group.addWithUpdate(object);

    }

    group
      .set("top", _clipboard.top + 5)
      .set("left", _clipboard.left + 5)
      .setCoords();

    _canvas
      .setActiveGroup(group)
      .add(group);

  } else {

    var object = fabric.util.object.clone(_clipboard);

    object
      .set("top", _clipboard.top + 5)
      .set("left", _clipboard.left + 5)
      .setCoords();

    _canvas
      .add(object)
      .setActiveObject(object)
      .renderAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of the clone() function has undergone a few changes recently, the following code works for me, using Fabric.js 1.7.0 (I note that you're using 1.5.0 in your fiddle):

```
  if (_clipboard.objects) {

    var group = new fabric.Group();

    for (var i in _clipboard.objects) {
        _clipboard.objects[i].clone(function (clonedObj) {
        group.addWithUpdate(clonedObj);
        if (group.size() == _clipboard.objects.length) {
            group
       .set("top", _clipboard.top + 5)
      .set("left", _clipboard.left + 5)
       .setCoords();

    _canvas
       .setActiveGroup(group)
       .add(group);
    }
  });


}
```

**EDIT:** I've had another go and it seems to be working properly now, it seems that with groups it's best to clone the group, and then in the callback go through and add each object to the canvas, and set it as active, as shown below

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whippet71/ygLcLsca/)

```
    _clipboard.clone(function (clonedObj) {
        _canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        clonedObj.set({
            left: clonedObj.left+10,
            top: clonedObj.top+10,
            evented: true
        });

        clonedObj.forEachObject(function(obj){
            obj.set('active', true);
            _canvas.add(obj);
        });

        _canvas.setActiveGroup(clonedObj).renderAll();
    });
```

Comment: That's great, I only have one issue it throws an error when the element is moved after cloning. The error is with Fabric.js:

fabric.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tl' of undefined(…)

Do you know of any way to avoid it?

Comment: I've also noticed that changing a cloned object also changes the original...i.e. if you try to resize it after cloning, both change?

Comment: You're right, should have tested that more thoroughly! Strange, as the docs claim that the clone() method does deep cloning, whereas fabric.util.object.clone only does a shallow clone

Comment: Answer updated - seems you need to clone the group first and then set the individual objects to active

Comment: Thank you John, thats done the trick. I had worked around it but it was a bit hacky. This is far cleaner.